# In what countries am I now allowed to talk about technical details of cryptography?

Tags: encryption

I hope this is the correct place to post this, otherwise I'm sorry.

The OpenSSL Legality section states:

> OR EVEN JUST COMMUNICATING TECHNICAL DETAILS ABOUT CRYPTOGRAPHY
>   SOFTWARE IS ILLEGAL IN SOME PARTS OF THE WORLD

I am wondering in which parts of the world you not allowed to talk about the technical details?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about laws, not crypto.

Comment: @cpast please point me in the direction of the stackexchange law site, and its about crypto law so its a bit of both.

Comment: There is none yet.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post a question on this entire site because there is no where to post it?

Comment: I doubt there are very many experts in international law on this site. Not sure where would be the best place to go, however.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660186/how-to-get-list-of-all-countries-and-the-encryption-standard-which-is-not-allowe

Comment: @Xela Correct. The fact that there's not yet a place to put this question doesn't mean you should put it on Crypto. There's a Law proposal on Area 51, but Crypto is about the mathematical internals of encryption algorithms, not about international law.

Comment: @cpast Well I thought since it is about crypto these are the people who mostly talk about it, so should know where they are not allow to talk about it.

Comment: @Xela Maybe this [link](http://www.cryptolaw.org/) is of use. This [map](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls-sum.htm) summarizes the crypto laws in place, as for 2010.